# How to implement "Go To Definition" extension in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

Which method in `vscode-languageserver::IConnection` has to be implemented to provide functionality "Go To Definition" over multiple files?

I was studying `Language Server Node Example` and vscode "API documentation", but I didn't find any info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code snippet illustrates how to implement "Go To Definition" using `vscode-languageserver`:

```ts
connection.onInitialize((params): InitializeResult => {
  ...
  return {
    capabilities: {
      definitionProvider: true,
      ...
    }
  }
});
    
connection.onDefinition((textDocumentIdentifier: TextDocumentIdentifier): Definition => {
  return Location.create(textDocumentIdentifier.uri, {
    start: { line: 2, character: 5 },
    end: { line: 2, character: 6 }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to create a class implementing the `DefinitionProvider`  and then register it using `registerDefinitionProvider`.

Take a look [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/blob/master/src/goMain.ts) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/blob/master/src/goDeclaration.ts) for an example.

Comment: Their extension depends directly on `vscode` modue. But thanks to you I found the connection points in the `vscode-languageserver`